# Frame rate issue with card views on Android app

Tags: android, android-cardview, frame-rate

I'm experiencing a huge frame rate / frame skip when scrolling through my card view. I read somewhere that it might be because i am loading images straight into the page rather than use Picasso but not sure if this would help. Wondering if anyone has experienced this before and knows how to fix ?

```
  <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardview1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cardview"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
        app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
        app:cardElevation="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Green Torso"
            android:textColor="@color/cardview_dark_background"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ShopGreenTorso"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/green_torso"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/register_button"
            android:shadowColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="20S Buy"
            android:textColor="@color/white">
        </Button>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

This is my code but i have only shown one cardview to keep the code short. The other 5 are identical to this just with different images.

Thanks all in advance.

[image]

Comment: Mine usually occur in large images try scaling down or optimizing it a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Determined that it was my device that was slow; Advice to anyone who is developing a mobile app is make sure to test on multiple devices. It did not run very smoothly on an LG G3, however was flawless on a OnePlus 3T. I'm sure there are people out there who could optimise this, but for most casual app developers, switching devices did the trick.